# Google Web App and Cookies Return Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cookies

I wanted to ask if it is possible to use Cookies in a Google Web App? I believe I had this working a few weeks back, but now when I try to read/write a Cookie, it is undefined.

I have tried using a jquery library, as well as doing this in javascript, but the console always returns a null or undefined response. As background, I have a Google Sheet, with a Web App attached. That app displays an HTML file.

In my document load event, I run this code:

```
   $.cookie("test","some value");
   console.log($.cookie("test"))
```

and the response is "undefined".  If I try using vanilla javascript, like this:

```
  document.cookie = "test=some value";
  console.log(document.cookie)
```

then the output is a blank line.

Are cookies blocked by Google Web Apps? Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT - I was asked to provide a minimal example.  This is a basic example that still does not display cookies.**

In a Google Sheet, I go to Tools-->Script Editor.  Here, I have two files:

**Code.js:**

```
function doGet(e) {
    output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    return output.evaluate();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script>
    document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
    var x = document.cookie;
     console.log( "Hello World" );
     console.log( x );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    index
  </body>
</html>
```

When the site loads, only "Hello World" is printed to the console

Comment: Depending on the browser, I believe third party cookies need to be enabled.

Comment: I have tried in Chrome and Firefox, enabling all cookies in both.  But, it does not change anything

Comment: Can't reproduce. Cookies show up here. Check whether the issue is somewhere else? Check the browser cookies directly from devtools

Comment: Even in Dev Tools, in the Application Tab, under Cookies, I can see a list of cookies.  But, the Cookie I create in my code does not show up there either.  I am using Google Enterprise.  Is it possible that the Admins were able to disable Cookies?  If so, how could I tell?

Comment: Highly unlikely that admins are able to interfere with your cookies. Do note that webapps are inside a iframe and you  should look in that iframe for cookies. On a broader note, Create a new project  to check for cookies. See  steps outlined here: [mcve]. Step 1(Restarting from scratch) is a great underutilized step

Comment: I have create as simple an example as possible, but the issue still occurs.  As I mentioned, this worked fine last week, which is why I am wondering if something with Google has changed?  I will post my new example above

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some playing around with the code, it seems it has to do with securing the cookie.  I am not sure if this is a new requirement (this code worked fine 2 weeks ago),  but now, if I create my cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "user=John; SameSite=none; secure";
```

It works fine.